# Export to word 2007

Tags: ssrs-2008

I only get the option to export to word, I do not get the option of exporting to word 2007. I'd like to have word 2007 as the default word export version but I can not find where on earth to change this. When I select export to word, the only file format even is only Word(*.doc).

Anyone? :)

Answer (score 0):

That is the only option. What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I tagged sql 2008 but that might not be that visible, it's 2008, not the RC.

Comment: Which release of 2008 R1 or R2? If I'm not mistaken I don't think it really matters though. .docx export will be available in the upcoming SQL Server release (Mar-12) so try and stay up to date.